Mi programa si compila pero no se termina de ejecutar
Estoy haciendo un programa en c++ como parte de un proyecto para mi profesor es sobre unas calificaciónes, pero me tiene que ir preguntando unidad por unidad como es que se evaluaran a los alumnos y cuando me pregunta cuantas ponderaciones quiero en la unidad 3 se termina de ejecutar repentinamente, en su mayoria termina de ejecutarse cuando me pregunta sobre los valores de la unidad 3.
El problema se presenta de distintas maneras, antes o despues de preguntar sobre la forma de evaluar en la unidad 3, pero antes tambien me ocurria lo mismo, la diferencia es que desaparecio cuando deje el programa, apague el computador y regrese el dia siguiente, desconozco si le habre movido a algo cuando me fui, o al regresar, el caso es que el programa aun no lo acabo, pero lo estoy haciendo por partes, y si esa parte no me termina de funcionar no podre avanzar con los siguientes puntos del programa,
Aquí el codigo:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n,i,s,u,j=0,m=0,b=0,l;
char letra; 
char A[n][30],N[3][20];
int B[n],U[n];
cout<<"\t\tProyecto Evaluacion de Calificaiones.\n\n";
cout<<"Cuantas unidades va a evaluar (numero).";
cin>>u;
cout<<"\nLas unidades se evaluaran todos igual?\nponga s para si, ponga n para no.\n";
cin>>letra;
switch (letra) {
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        cout << "Has seleccionado 's'.\n" << endl;
        cout<<"Cuantas ponderaciones va a evaluar (numero):";
        cin>>n;
        cout<<endl; 
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la ponderacion "<<i+1<<".";
        cin>>A[i];
        }   
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        cout << "Has seleccionado 'n'.\n" << endl;
        for(j=0; j<u; j++){
        cout<<"\nunidad "<<j+1<<endl;   
        cout<<"Cuantas ponderaciones va a evaluar (numero):";
        cin>>U[j];
        n=U[j];
        cout<<endl;
        
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            
            cout<<i;
            cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la ponderacion "<<i+1<<".";
            cin>>A[m];
            m++;
        }}
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Letra no válida. Ingresa 's' o 'n'." << endl;
        break;
}
for(m=0; m<11; m++){
    cout<<"Ponderacion "<<m+1<<".";
    cout<<A[m]<<endl;
    }

cout<<"\nCuanto porcentaje le dara a cada poderacion (en porcentajes).\n\n";
cout<<"La suma del total de ponderaciones debe ser 100.\n";
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<<A[i]<<":";
    cin>>B[i];
    s += B[i];
}
s -= 1;
if(s<100){
        cout<<"La suma de ponderaciones no alcanza lo soliciatado.";
    }
    if(s>100){
        cout<<"La suma de ponderaciones sobrepasa lo solicitado.";
    }
cout<<"\tIngrese el nombre del estudiante."<<endl;
cin>>N[1];
cout<<"Ingrese el primer apellido del estudiante."<<endl;
cin>>N[2];  
cout<<"Ingrese el segundo apellido del estudiante."<<endl;
cin>>N[3];  


return 0;   
}

Aquí la prueba:


Los arreglos comienzan por 0, no 1. Ojo con N[3]

Además de lo que comenta Mateo, ¿Qué valor tiene la variable n cuando declaras tus arrays con char A[n][30], int B[n]  e int U[n]?.... Un consejo, no uses variables sin inicializar previamente en  C/C++, son muy pocos los casos donde esto no es un comportamiento indefinido...

gracias!!, justo era eso

El problema está al principio, por cómo defines las variables:
int n,i,s,u,j=0,m=0,b=0,l;
char letra; 
char A[n][30],N[3][20];
int B[n],U[n];

Si prestas atención, 3 de los arreglos tienen n elementos. Pero, n es una variable, y cuánto vale n? Es importante inicializar todas las variables.
Como podrás saber, algunos compiladores admiten arreglos de tamaño variable (VLA). Si planeas que tu código sea portable, es mejor no depender de una característica que el compilador puede soportar o no.
Por otra parte n no está inicializada, así que los arreglos creados son de un tamaño desconocido. Entonces, llegado cierto punto el programa explota, porque intenta acceder a una posición de memoria que no le corresponde. Primero tienes que darle un valor a n y luego definirlos. Por ejemplo:
cin >> n;
char A[n][30];
int B[n],U[n];

Sugiero que utilices memoria dinámica. O mejor aún clases de la librería estándar, como string y vector. Por ejemplo:
vector<string> A;
vector<int> B, U;

De este modo no tienes que preocuparte por gestionar la memoria. Simplemente vas agregando elementos con la función push_back y acceder a ellos como si de un arreglo se tratara.

Gracias por la explicación, lo hice y el programa dejo de fallar. Lección aprendida no dejar variables indefinidas
